# web-service to get sharepoint data gives error

Tags: php, web-services, sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2007

I am executing following in my web-service file to get the sharepoint list data:

```
$authParams = array('login' => 'user', 'password' => 'pass');

/* A string that contains either the display name or the GUID for the list.
 * It is recommended that you use the GUID, which must be surrounded by curly
 * braces ({}).
 */
$listName = "TestList1";
$rowLimit = '150';

$wsdl = "http://192.168.1.197:5000/sharepoint/ListsWSDL.wsdl"; 

//Creating the SOAP client and initializing the GetListItems method parameters
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $authParams);
$params = array('listName' => $listName, 'rowLimit' => $rowLimit);

//Calling the GetListItems Web Service
$rawXMLresponse = null;
try{
    $rawXMLresponse = $soapClient->GetListItems($params)->GetListItemsResult->any;
}
catch(SoapFault $fault){
    echo 'Fault code: '.$fault->faultcode;
    echo 'Fault string: '.$fault->faultstring;
}
```

But it is going into the catch block with following error:

```
Fault code: HTTPFault string: Not Found
```

what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://[sharepoint site url]/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL` for the wsdl,

but the actual webservice exists on `http://[sharepoint site url]/_vti_bin/lists.asmx`

This [list of webservices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29.aspx) has a page showing the url for each service.

Comment: i generated the wsdl file by this only and stored it in local /sharepoint folder

Comment: You still have to call the webservice using the correct url or you will get a 404 response.

Comment: the path 'http://192.168.1.197:5000/sharepoint/ListsWSDL.wsdl'is the path to my local folder where the generated wsdl file was stored. And this is how i call it.